# Trees with two eigenvalues?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Is it possible for a tree of order $n$ ($n$ even) to have eigenvalues $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_1, -\lambda_1, \ldots, -\lambda_1)$ ? Or perhaps $(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_1, 0,-\lambda_1, \ldots, -\lambda_1)$ if $n$ is odd ?

Thanks.

Comment: try the connected graph with 2 nodes

Comment: I was after something for generic $n$. Thanks though :)

Comment: notice that, if $n$ even, then $A^2 = \lambda_1^2 I$, meaning that there are no path of length 2 between different nodes, that is impossible if $n>2$

Comment: Yes of course! Thanks.